# Using LEFT & FIND in a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I currently use a Workbook with 2 worksheets, one containing the original data (VariantMetrics-Filtered) which looks like:

```
c.1000T>A;c.1000T>A;c.955T>A
```

and the other containing a formula combining "LEFT" and "FIND" which allows me grabbing just the first part of the data until the first semicolon. The current formula looks like the one below:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT('VariantMetrics-Filtered'!C2,FIND(";",'VariantMetrics-Filtered'!C2)-1),'VariantMetrics-Filtered'!C2)
```

I would like to use a VBA macro to make things cleaner since the formula references cells and this is not optimal.
I came up with the code below, but I get an error: Expected: end of statement for the ";".
I don't understand why since I think that the syntax for "LEFT" is correct.

```
Sub Remove_duplicates()
'
'

  Dim cell As Range
 
  Set cell = Range("D2:D4000")
    cell.Formula = IFERROR(Left(ActiveCell, Find(";", ActiveCell) - 1),ActiveCell)
    
    
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should look something like this. It needs to be a string and quotes inside the string need to be doubled as you can see at `…Find("";""…`

```
cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(Left(" & ActiveCell.Address & ", Find("";""," & ActiveCell.Address & ") - 1)," & ActiveCell.Address & ")"
```

The `ActiveCell` is probably an issue here. I think you should replace it with the first cell of your `Range("D2:D4000")` Eg `C2`.

Use `cell.Resize(1, 1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Address(False, False)` instead of `ActiveCell.Address` above.

Comment: Dear PEH, thank you for the hint. However, it replaces all values by "0" and doesn't keep any data. However, I see that it might help solving the problem. I will work on it! Cheers.

Comment: @Sylvain.A See my edit.

Comment: just make sure the formula you write in `cell.Formula = ""` is the formula you would write in `D2` (the first cell of your defined range). Excel will adjust the formula automaticall for the other cells.

Comment: Hi PEH, thank you for the edit! As you wrote the issue was related to the fact that the data is in the same cell as the formula. I guess it is impossible to do this and I need to select another cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about retaining the original data then you don't need to use a formula and can just have the macro overwrite the original data.

The `instr` function is similar to the `find` formula.

```
Sub Remove_duplicates()

  Dim cell As Range, rng as Range
  Dim str as String
 
  Set rng = Range("D2:D4000")
    
    For each Cell in Rng
      str = Cell.value
      
      If Instr(str,";")>0 Then
        str = Left(str,Instr(str,";")-1)
        Cell.Value = str
      End if

    Next cell
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi mugron, thank you for your answer! I indeed don't care about retaining the original data. However, there seem to be a syntax error in your code at this level ``` If INSTR(str,";")>) Then ``` I tried the double quotations marks but it didn't work. I will try to solve it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Forgot the 0 after >. Updated now. Hopefully that helps. You shouldn't need double quotation marks either.

Comment: Hi mugron, I still receive a syntax error message for this part of the code. But thanks for the help!
I wonder if it is not related to the fact that there should be another expression after the ";",
But since I am not familiar with InStr. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the final code that works (I got help from a colleague) is:

```
Sub Remove_duplicates()

  Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
  Dim str As String
 
  Set rng = Range("Q2:Q4000")
    
For Each cell In rng
      str = cell.Value
      
      If InStr(str, ";") Then
        str = Left(str, InStr(str, ";") - 1)
        cell.Value = str
      End If

Next cell

       
End Sub
```

I hope it can be useful to someone. And thanks again for the hints!